# Are there statements in set theory about arithmetic beyond the reach of the analytical hierarchy?

Tags: logic, set-theory, arithmetic, higher-order-logic

Even if the answer were negative for arithmetics(I have no idea), in the more general case: Can any mathematical statement be expressed as a $\Delta_m^n$ (with n, m belongs to N) statement in a chosen language? Or are there statements of set theory that cannot be translated into $\Delta_m^n$ statements? (clarification: by $\Delta_m^n$ I mean either $\Sigma_m^n$ or $\Pi_m^n$, not necessarily both)

Sorry I just realized how confusing this question is (or I mean, not what I wanted to ask originally, as for some reason there is a bug in my brain that makes me think that the analytical hierarchy is the same as arbitrary high-order logic), So I will put the questions as answered and restate the question in a form that (I hope) makes sense.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is a "statement about arithmetic"? Is a statement about the cardinality of $V_{\omega+\omega+1}$ a $\Delta^n_m$ statement?

Comment: I am not sure what is strictly arithmetical for mathematicians. I guess any statement involving the properties of natural numbers? Regarding your question about that statement: I have no idea, I don't really know that much about set theory, that is why I am asking (I am asking beyond my reach, I guess?)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo The closet that I know to an answer is that the continuum hypothesis is (equivalent to) a $\Sigma^2_1$ formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sentence in the analytical hierarchy that is provably equivalent to the generalized continuum hypothesis.  ("Provably" means in the usual axiomatization of set theory, ZFC.)

Comment: is this a limitation of the analytical hierarchy or of ZFC? (I think the answer is obvious, but just to be sure)

Comment: Until we have a clear idea whether GCH is true or not, I wouldn't consider its independence from ZFC (or the more general fact in my answer) to be a limitation of ZFC, so I call this a limitation of the analytical hierarchy --- it simply doesn't express information about arbitrary cardinals (like GCH).  If we knew whether GCH is true or not, then it would be reasonable to add it or its negation to ZFC as a new axiom, thereby making GCH provably equivalent to *very* a low-level arithmetical sentence, namely $0=0$ if it's true and $0=1$ if it's false.

Comment: I think you pretty much answered my question, but just one detail. You say that that the analytical hierarchy doesn't express information about arbitrary cardinals (like GCH), but how is this limitation?: is it strong enough to express up to a known specific cardinal? or do any arbitrary but specific cardinal we can define can be expressed by the analytical hierarchy?

Comment: I mean, is any axiom about a specific cardinal (however huge) expressible in the analytical hierarchy? is the GCH a step beyond those large cardinal axioms, if so, are there any other examples that you know that cannot be expressed by the analytical hierarchy? thanks, and sorry if I'm asking too much.